# Which data is thrown away in queue if publish and spinonce rate is different?

Tags: ros, queue, spinonce, callbackqueue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I read that SpinOnce does not only make callback, but it will also clean the queue if possible. **is that right?**

Let's say publisher publish alphabets (a,b,c,...) at 9hz, and subscriber call Spinonce at 3hz.

So publisher will publish a,b,c to queue. Then subscriber does spinonce, getting a (because queue is First in first out) and empty the queue.Now the queue is empty.
Next, publisher will publish d,e,f to queue. Then subscriber does spinonce, getting d and empty the queue.Now the queue is empty.
Next, publisher will publish g,h,i to queue. Then subscriber does spinonce, getting g and empty the queue.Now the queue is empty.

So at the end what the subscriber gets is a,d,g,...

Is that right? Please explain

**EDIT (additional question)**
Where should we call ros::spin() or ros::spinOnce()? Is it in the publisher code, or subscriber code? and why is so?

In this [tutorial of publisher-subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)
It calls ros::spinOnce() in the publisher code, and it also calls ros::spin() in subscriber code. Why is that so? please explain..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241608/which-data-is-thrown-away-in-queue-if-publish-and-spinonce-rate-is-different?/) by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 582 on 2016-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No

SpinOnce can call multiple callbacks if necessary. spinOnce will call callback for each message in a queue separately, and only then remove it from a queue. Thus you will get callback for each one. Callbacks will be one after another as fast as possible.

Your receiver will get: a,b,c ...pause... d,e,f.... pause... g,h,i

This is assuming your queue length is sufficient. if queue gets full, you will start loosing messages.

---

Originally posted by [Marcin Bogdanski](https://answers.ros.org/users/26406/marcin-bogdanski/) with karma: 231 on 2016-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-12**:
"If necessary". When is it necessary? Is it when there is still stuffs on the queue after the SpinOnce is called?

**Comment by [Marcin Bogdanski](https://answers.ros.org/users/26406/marcin-bogdanski/) on 2016-08-14**:
"If necessary" == If there is more than one message on the queue.

SpinOnce will call a callback once for each message on the queue before removing it. And through that it will clear the whole queue. As far as I know it will never remove message without calling a callback.

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-14**:
So anyway we will still get all of the datas/messages?(assuming the queue size is big enough).

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-14**:
Also, If I use ros::spin instead of spinOnce, I will just need to call it once, and it will callback automatically everytime a message arrives. Is that right?

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-14**:
I have additional question, I edited the question already. Could you please help to asnwer? Thankss